# Deleting records using prepared statement with more than 2 parameters

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, sql-delete

I am using prepared statement for doing some operations on my database. I have table as below:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|Field  |    Type  |    Size |   Key  |  Text            |
+--------------------------------------------------------+           
|X1DEL  |  Char    |     1   |     2  | Status           |  
|X1CMP  |  Zoned   |     3   |     1  | Company No.      | 
|X1ORD  |  Zoned   |     9   |     2  | Order Number     | 
|X1TYPE |  Char    |     1   |     1  | Transaction Type |
|X1ORDT |  Zoned   |     8   |     0  | Order Date       |
|X1CUST |  Char    |    10   |     0  | Customer Number  |
|X1PO   |  Char    |    20   |     0  | PO Number        |
|X1OTOT |  Zoned   |    11   |     2  | Order Total      |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am doing one delete query as `delete from my_table where field=?` for single parameter.
I have created query for 2 parameters as `delete from my_table where field=? and type=?`
Again now i want to execute query for 4 to 5 parameters. I am writing a query as `delete from my_table where field=?,type=?,size=? and key=?` 
I have tried for this query but not getting result.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to do. If you want to create a query with 4 conditions, then create one (and no, `,` is not a proper way to separate conditions, you need to use `AND` or `OR`).

Comment: will it work for more than two parameters?

Comment: I had a thought as it will not work for more than 2 parameters so i asked for the query

Comment: You can use as many parameters as your database or driver supports. I am unsure why that wouldn't be obvious, so I assume you actually want to do something else.

Comment: The query with more than two parameters in your question is simply wrong: it has syntax errors. It has nothing to do with the number of parameters.

Comment: No i wanted to do it for more than two parameters so i thought it would not be possible to do by `and` I know i did a wrong query but i wanted to show you what i did so i have written that query
Now i will try by your approach thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design, [use prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#supply_values_ps) to build queries with any number of parameters.

```
final String sql = "delete from my_table where field=? and type=? and size=? and key=?";
```

If your parameters are in a `collection` you can use the advice of the linked tutorial and `"make coding easier by using a for loop or a while loop to set values for input parameters"`. Depending on the `type` and number of the parameters you are supplying, you need to call the appropriate `.set` method for each of them.

```
 //assuming con (DB connection) is properly setup
 final PreparedStatment statement = con.prepareStatement(sql); 
 statement.setString(1, "X1DEL");
 statement.setString(2, "CHAR");
 statement.setInt(3,1);
 statement.setInt(4, 2);

 //... etc
```

You have to remember that prepared statements are `1-based` indexing.

Comment: why the String and prepared statement are final here

Comment: Mainly due to conventions from work experiences which have become habit.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you do it that way when the 2 parameter example showed you the right thing to do?

```
delete from my_table where field = ? and type = ? and size = ? and key = ?
```

Comment: You could have tried it yourself and answered easily in the 39 minutes that have passed since you posted this comment.  It'll only fail if you code it badly.